# Newton's second law: Calculate distance to accelerate mass with force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Can I use Newton's second law for calculating distance to accelerate a mass with some force? Let's say I want to accelerate mass of 1 kilogram by applying force of 1 Newton from 0 kmph to 10 kmph. After how long distance will speed reach 10 kmph? How can I calculate this?

(Side question: how to ask Wolfram Alpha to solve this problem?)

Comment: if your force is constant you can use $x=x_0 + v_0*t + \frac{F}{m}*\frac{t^2}{2}$ which is derived from Newton's second law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a group of equations, generically called the [SUVAT equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#SUVAT_equations), that can be obtained by integrating the second law. In this case it sounds as if you want the equation:

$$ v^2 = u^2 + 2as $$

You know the initial, $u$, and final, $v$, velocities and the acceleration, $a$, so you can rearrange the equation to calculate the distance $s$.

Comment: Thanks, I can calculate $a$ from $F=ma$ and I'll have my answer!

Answer (score 0):

A useful equation to calculate space when an object is accelerated is:
$$S=\frac{v_f^2-v_i^2}{2a}$$
This comes from $S=\frac12at^2$ by because $t=\frac va$

So because $a=\frac Fm$ the final equation is:
$$S=\frac{m\cdot(v_f^2-v_i^2)}{2F}$$

Comment: Thanks, if I get this corractly, integration of 2nd Newton's law is in equation $S = \frac{1}{2}at^{2}$.